# Transform.FindChild(string) is obsolete. What do I type instead? I am learning C#/unity through an old tutorial

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

`playerName = transform.FindChild("PlayerInfoContainer").FindChild("PlayerPortrait").FindChild("PlayerName").GetComponent<Text> ();`

I am getting a warning here about depreciated code and to use Find([mscorlib] System.String) instead. But I am not sure what I am supposed to use instead for this. Unity said it would upgrade it for me but I clicked the wrong button on the pop up and now the unity api updater is grayed out for me. Can anyone help please.

Comment: use transform.Find();
https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Transform.Find.html

Comment: Actually it tells you to use find in the error

Answer (score 0):

You could try finding the player GameObject and extracting the name from the GameObject, but you will need to add a tag to your player object.

something like this:

```
playerName = GameObject.FindObjectWithTag("Player").name;
```